# How long does it take to travel from one end of the Bajoran Wormhole to the other?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, wormhole

My question is in the title. How long would it take to travel from one end of the Bajoran Wormhole to the other, assuming that there is no way to exit the wormhole by, for example, Quasar M92? I've already had that question answered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is addressed in the Star Trek factbook [Stellar Cartography: The Starfleet Reference Library](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Stellar_Cartography:_The_Starfleet_Reference_Library). Travel through the wormhole will...

> *"...cut a 70,000 light-year journey between the two quadrants **down to two
>   minutes".***

Note that in practice, the length of wormhole travel seems to be largely driven by the plot. The [series bible](http://leethomson.myzen.co.uk/Star_Trek/3_Deep_Space_Nine/Star_Trek_-_Deep_Space_Nine_Bible.pdf) simply describes it as "a *brief journey*" and in some episodes it can take very much longer, especially if one is flying slowly in the hopes of encountering a Prophet.

Comment: Yeah. Given that ships are still traveling under their own power when inside the wormhole, it seems that the time would depend on the individual engine's speed, with perhaps a lower limit.

Comment: @ench Presumably the bargain struck by Sisko with the wormhole aliens affects it in someway too.